# general topology exercise 777

Tags: general-topology

Let f : $S^1$ → R be continuous, where $S^1$ is the unit circle in $R^2$.
(a) Show that there is a point z ∈ $S^1$ such that f(z) = f(−z).
[z = (x; y), −z = (−x;−y)]\
(b) Show that f is not surjective.

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Did you try looking at $F(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$? It is continuous.

Comment: Did you solve the first 776 exercises?

Answer (score 4):

HINTS: $S^1$ is compact and connected. The map $S^1\to\Bbb R:z\mapsto f(z)-f(-z)$ is useful.

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

(a) Let $g(z)=f(z)-f(-z)$ and apply the Intermediate Value Theorem.

(b) You know that $S^1$ is compact.  What do you know about the image of a compact space under a continuous map?

Comment: Compact...and connected (even path-connected)...